# How Product Detail View is calculated in GA's Product Performance Report?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to understand how Product Details view is calculated? Is it count of hit or unique hit? For eg - If a user has viewed 2 products 5 times in his visit, product detail view would be 5 or 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the **Product Detail Views** definition: Number of times users viewed the product-detail page (Enhanced Ecommerce).

However, I can confirm that it is the number of times that the `detail` interaction is sent to Google Analytics.

So to answer your question the value you will see is 5.

Comment: Thanks Michele !
So this also implies that value "Product_View" of shopping-stage dimension is set for detail interactions?
Which means means "Product Detail View" of product performance report is hit basis not sessions basis?

Comment: Enhanced Ecommerce is focused on the products for which it is correct that in that case it is not based on the session. For this reason there is also a custom dimension with product scope. The information associated with a product is within the scope of the product (or hit) that which refers to the user, such as the sessions that have viewed a product, are at the session level.

Comment: Thanks Michele ! My confusion is resolved. I thought that product detail view of product performance metrics is session based i.e. no of session in which a product is viewed. But you clarified it, its on hit basis.